# How to Show Single Product - 4 Data by ID in Custom Page without over-riding the existing Woo-Commerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to show **Single Product Data** in **Custom Page** by given **Category ID** but when I used the below code:

`<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'product_cat' => 'category-id' );
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
get_template_part( 'woocommerce/archive-product', 'page' );
?>`

It only fetch data like this when I insert `print_r(query_posts( $args ))`

then I got

`Array
(
    [0] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 391
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2018-08-03 08:55:15
            [post_date_gmt] => 2018-08-03 08:55:15
            [post_content] => 
            [post_title] => 4 Bars
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => publish
            [comment_status] => open
            [ping_status] => closed
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => 4-bars
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2018-08-03 09:09:22
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2018-08-03 09:09:22
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => http://localhost/abc/?post_type=product&p=391
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => product
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
        )
)`

so, If you consider that `[guid] => link`, which will re-direct me in **single-product.php** page, so, I want the all single product data shown according to **category ID** in **Custom Page**; I'm not getting a clue that How could I do?
Let me know, if you people have any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your query returns an array of posts (query all products belonging to specific cat product cat), in your case it looks like there's ony one.
To display a list on your custom page you've to iterate the array with:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'product_cat' => 'category-id' );//note that this looks like a mistake, if you want to query by id this should be an integer or an integer variable (i.e. $catid coming from somewere earlier defined) 
$query = new WP_Query($args);
$posts = $query->posts;
foreach($posts as $post) {
  // Do your stuff, e.g.
  // echo $post->post_name;
  get_template_part( 'woocommerce/single-product');//this may or not work, it possibly need some adjustment
}
```